# "Caught ImportError while rendering: No module named urls" in Admin

Tags: python, django-admin, apache2, mod-wsgi, slicehost

I have recently created an account at SliceHost and made a new Slice. I copied my new project in and changed the paths in settings, and every file. But, when i try to access the admin interface, I get this error:

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /admin/
Caught ImportError while rendering: No module named urls

In template /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/base.html, error at line 31
Caught ImportError while rendering: No module named urls
```

Anyone know why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed my problem. It was because I was at the wrong version of Haystack. Thanks though guys.

Comment: i think i might have a similar error, what did you do to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify the above answer, when you install from `pip` you can grab `haystack` or `django-haystack`. Likewise for `typogrify` and surely other packages.

In other words, one of the `INSTALLED_APPS` isn't correct.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I had this error when importing urls at root level:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^tag/', include('tag.urls')),    
#(...)
```

The file "tag/urls.py" was missing. 
So. No module named urls.
A much better error message would be

*Module 'urls.py' not found in app 'tag/'*

or something similar.